# how to embed javascript into act_window model in openerp 7

Tags: javascript, odoo

I have action configuration like this :

```
<record id="view_rnd_compare_version_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">rnd.compare.version.form</field>
    <field name="model">pti.rnd.batch.record.version.compare</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Compare Version" version="7.0">
            <group colspan="4" col="4">
                <field name="br_id"/>
                <field name="old_formula"/>
                <field name="old_version"/>
                <field name="new_formula"/>
                <field name="new_version"/>
            </group>
            <button name="compare" string="Compare"/>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>

<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_rnd_compare1">
    <field name="name">Compare Version</field>
    <field name="res_model">pti.rnd.batch.record.version.compare</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">form</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="view_rnd_compare_version_form"/>
    <field name="target">new</field>
    <field name="nodestroy">True</field>
</record>
```

My questions is how to embed javascript into act_window thus I can doing anything regarding any field and request any data from openerp? Thank you.

Comment: What you want to do ? be more clear with your aim.

Comment: I want to add handler for button click event that will doing something. If user click "compare" button, it trigger/call my javascript function. Is that clear enough? Please let me know if it still missing info. Thanks.